# Bouncy Castle SHA256withECDSA

Tags: java, bouncycastle

I'm new about Sign and Crypto... I'm tring to implement Sign a String whit bouncy castle jars but I do not understand how start... I just need a little example how generate a Asymetric Key pair,use it to sign a string and verify it using  SHA256withECDSA whit DER or RAW.

thanks all.

Comment: there are examples on SO.